# jQuery wrap list elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have my markup like a numbers of li inside ul.like this.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="test"><a href="#">dhsd</a></li>
<li class="test"><a href="#">sdghds</a></li>
- - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - -
- - - -- - - - - - -- -- - - - -- -
<li class="lang-switch language_en"><a href="#">en</a></li>
<li class="lang-switch language_es"><a href="#">es</a></li>
<li class="lang-switch language_de"><a href="#">de</a></li>
<li class="lang-switch language_ja"><a href="#">ja</a></li>
</ul>
```

From this you can see after a number of li the last four have the class name lang-switch.
I want to wrap the markup those li whose class is lang-switch . So that my markup should be like this

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="test"><a href="#">dhsd</a></li>
<li class="test"><a href="#">sdghds</a></li>
- - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - -
- - - -- - - - - - -- -- - - - -- -
<ul class="listing">
  <li class="lang-switch language_en"><a href="#">en</a></li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_es"><a href="#">es</a></li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_de"><a href="#">de</a></li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_ja"><a href="#">ja</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

So to add a wrap I made a jquery like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var LangList = jQuery('ul#menu').find('li.lang-switch');
    jQuery(LangList).wrap('<ul class="test"></ul>');
  });
```

but this one is doing wrap like this

```
<ul class="test">
  <li class="lang-switch language_en"><a href="#">en</a></li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="test">
  <li class="lang-switch language_es"><a href="#">es</a></li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="test">
  <li class="lang-switch language_de"><a href="#">de</a></li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="test">
  <li class="lang-switch language_ja"><a href="#">ja</a></li>
 </ul>
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to do a wrap for theose listings with the same class.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```
var LangList = jQuery('ul#menu').find('li.lang-switch');
LangList.wrapAll('<ul class="test"></ul>');
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2x72/)

As Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy points out you don't need too again convert `LangList` into a jQuery object, you because it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: There is no need to convert a jquery object again into a jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/),

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var LangList = jQuery('ul#menu').find('li.lang-switch');
    LangList.wrapAll('<ul class="test"></ul>');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use **wrapAll** in jquery

```
 $(".lang-switch").wrapAll("<div class=listing></div>");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SxPxN/151/)